# Flow errors on Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise, flowtype

I have multiple functions in this application that return promises and are all annotated with Flow types. There are 2 however, that are giving me flow errors (they do work) that I can't seem to decipher. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

**FUNCTION 1**

**Call**

```
const posts = await getPostRoutes({ brand, reusables, acf, wp })
```

**Declaration**

```
export async function getPostRoutes (
  { brand, reusables, acf, wp } :
  { brand: PropsBrand, reusables: Object, acf: string, wp: string },

) : Promise<Array<{
  path: string,
  component: string,
  getProps: Function,
}>> {
  const { data: posts_index } = await axios.get(`${acf}/options/posts_index`)
  const { data: posts } = await axios.get(`${wp}/posts?_embed`)

  return [{
    path: `${posts_index.acf.posts_index_blog_slug}`,
    component: 'src/containers/Posts',
    getProps: () => ({
      brand,
      title: posts_index.acf.posts_index_blog_title,
      subtitle: posts_index.acf.posts_index_blog_subtitle,
      reusables: {
        contact_columns: reusables['3_columns_contact_block_contact_columns'],
      },
    }),
    children: posts.map(post => ({
      path: `/${post.slug}`,
      component: 'src/containers/Posts/Post',
      getProps: () => ({
        ...cleanWPJson(post),
        brand,
        reusables: {
          ball_rolling_cta: {
            image: reusables.ball_rolling_cta_background_image,
            label: reusables.ball_rolling_cta_label,
            link: reusables.ball_rolling_cta_link,
          },
        },
      }),
    })),
  }]
}
```

**Flow Error**

```
[flow] Promise (This type is incompatible with the expected param type of union: type application of class `Promise` | type parameter `T` of await Member 1: type application of class `Promise` Error: type application of async return This type is incompatible with the expected return type of type application of identifier `Promise` Member 2: type parameter `T` of await Error: Promise This type is incompatible with $Iterable)
```

**FUNCTION 2**

**Call**

```
const recentPortfolioPieces = await getRecentPortfolioPieces({ wp, count: 3 })
```

**Declaration**

```
export async function getRecentPortfolioPieces (
  { wp, count } : { wp: string, count: number},

) : Promise<Array<{
  title: string,
  id: number,
  categories: Array<Object>,
  slug: string,
  thumbnail: {
    alt: string,
    url: string,
  },
}>> {
  const { data: recentPortfolioPieces } = await axios.get(`${wp}/portfolio?per_page=${count}`)
  return recentPortfolioPieces.map(piece => {
    return {
      title: piece.title.rendered,
      id: piece.id,
      categories: piece.pure_taxonomies.portfolio_cat,
      slug: '',
      thumbnail: {
        alt: '',
        url: '',
      },
    }
  })
}
```

**Flow Error**

```
[flow] Promise (This type is incompatible with the expected param type of union: type application of class `Promise` | type parameter `T` of await Member 1: type application of class `Promise` Error: object literal This type is incompatible with the expected param type of object type Member 2: type parameter `T` of await Error: object literal This type is incompatible with the expected param type of object type)
```

I'm sure it's something about inherent about how Flow understands promises that i'm missing here. Again, any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've found this link useful:https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5294